# Retrieving data from objects with a variable in nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, object

How to get values from an object in nodejs?

`let person = {temperature:[35,36],humidity:[85,90,89};`

```
let y = req.query.id; (which is `temperature`)
console.log(person.y);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get values from a nodejs object you can do it in the following way

Getting it directly `person.temparature` or `person[myvar]`

Or by iteration:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(person)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`); // key = 'temperature', value = [35,36] for the first entry (temperature)
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Welcome to SO! Congratulations for the correct answer and upvote. As layout advice, I suggest that you use the link more discrete, like [here](http://www.fakeexample.com)  and not like [http://www.fakeexample.com](http://www.fakeexample.com)